# Can't empty my array in my to-do list

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've a to-do list where you can add tasks, complete them and delete them. Now I want a function that deletes the entire list. Which means that I want to empty the whole array. 
The problem is that, when I click "Delete list", the list stays intact. I've used `alert("test");` and therefor I know that the function is being called on right. So how come the list is still there? 
The code for the delete function is at the bottom.

```
window.onload = function() {
var taskList = [];                                          

var ul = document.getElementById("ulList");

// set focus on the text field
document.getElementById("toDoTask").focus();

// find the add id and onclick, go to function addTolist
document.getElementById("add").onclick = addToList;
document.getElementById("delete").onclick = deleteList;


/*
 *  Function that add tasks to the list and creates the list that appends to the ul element in the html
 *  Just alert an error if the user didnt add a task
 */

function addToList() {
    var task = document.getElementById("toDoTask").value;

    // check if user forgot to write a task
    if(task.length == 0){
        alert("You forgot to add a task");


    } 

    else {
        // add task to the taskList array
        taskList.push(task);  

        for(i =0; i < taskList.length; i++) {

            // create element li and add task to it
            var li = document.createElement('li');                         
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(taskList[i]));        

            // create imgDelete, add [x] and append to li
            var imgDelete = document.createElement('img');
            imgDelete.src = 'img/delete.png';
            imgDelete.addEventListener("click", deleteTask);
            li.appendChild(imgDelete);

            // create spanComplete, add [done] and append to li
            var imgComplete = document.createElement('img');
            imgComplete.src = 'img/complete.png';
            imgComplete.addEventListener("click", completeTask);
            li.appendChild(imgComplete);                                  
        }

        //append li to ul 

        ul.appendChild(li);

    }

}

/*
 * Complete the task by adding a class that change the color to green and add a line-through.
 * 
 */

function completeTask() {
    // set the default parent to li
    var li = this.parentNode;
    li.className = "line-through";
}

/*
 * Delete the task 
 * 
 */

function deleteTask() {
    var li = this.parentNode;
    ul.removeChild(li);
}

function deleteList() {
    taskList= [] ;
}

};
```

If you got some other comments about the code, please tell. Very new at this and willing to learn!

Comment: I don't think I see you refreshing the list after delete. You've just emptied the array.

Comment: Mike meant that you need to invoke `addToList()` in `deleteList()` just after setting ` taskList= [] ;`. Correct @MikeCheel ?

Comment: I wouldn't code it like this exactly but deleteList is the handler for the click of 'delete'. It empties out the task array but don;t see where it clears the UI. Clicking an individual item appears to clear out a single item but I don't see anything that clears all.

Comment: Do anyone have an example on how the function could clear the ul? When I try I get _Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'._ Which points to the `ul.appendChild(li);` in the `updateList`function (which I know have created and creates the list)

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `addToList()` function, you reconstruct the task list displayed on-screen from your array of tasks.

Extract this logic into a function called `updateList()`, and call it from `addToList()` after pushing into the array.

Then, in the `deleteList()` function, call `updateList()` too after clearing the array.

I don't see you removing all the existing elements before re-adding them. You could do:

```
while (taskList.firstChild) {
    taskList.removeChild(taskList.firstChild);
}
```

Note, too, that it's not necessary to empty and repopulate the entire list: you could keep the node's associated with your task items in the array, and handle them 1 by 1.

Comment: I cant get it right. I did what you said and created a updateList() and called it from addToList()and it worked the way it suppose to. So I guess that I don't really understand the delete function. Here is the end of the code now; `function deleteList() { taskList= []; while(taskList.ul) { taskList.removeChild(taskList.ul); } }` The rest is pretty much the same, except for the new function.

Comment: I checked and the array is empty, so its the deleting of the list that I don't get to work. I tried changing ul to li but it didn't work either.